# Suggestions needed regarding an approach for Bot announcement System

Tags: java, spring-boot, parallel-processing, cisco, webex

We'd implemented a Java based bot announcement system it will accept a max of 60k
users per request, we have used parallel processing with a 300 threads. It was able to complete the task in approx 3 to 4 hours.

The problem is if one user initiated
a task until completion of the first task its not processing another request. I need to make it flexible for multiple users also scheduled message sending

someone suggest me an approach to implement a Effective Bot anmouncement System which can allow multiple user requests & per request max 60k users .

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to provide a lot more detail here. What is a 'bot announcement' system? My guess, going only on what you've written ("if one user initiated a task until completion of the first task its not processing another request") is that you have some lock somewhere that is being held. Do you have locking inside some datastructure, or database somewhere?

Comment: We don't have any locking functionality, As the thread pool was occupied by previous task 300 threads the new request is waiting till the past request related processing completed, just Fyi https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bot-conversations/bots-conversations#:~:text=When%20a%20user%20sends%20a,Microsoft%20Teams%20for%20more%20details.